# Ajuda com o uso da biblioteca igraph e timeorded no R

Tags: r, grafo

Estou usando a lib 'igraph' e 'timeorded' (http://www.benjaminblonder.org/timeorderednetworks/)  para trabalhar com grafos temporais. Tenho o seguinte grafo temporal:

```
"graph.txt":

a c 1 1

a d 2 2

b d 2 2

c d 3 3

d b 3 3
```

[image: Representação do arquivo graph.txt em forma de grafo temporal]

Meu código:

```
library(igraph)
library(plyr)
library(timeordered)


g <- read.table("C:/Users/Filli/Desktop/testes/graph.txt", head= TRUE)
g <- generatetonetwork(g)
tdAll <- generatetimedeltas(1,4,3)
graphAgre <- generatenetworkslices(g, tdAll)
```

A variável 'graphAgre' é a união de todos os grafos, do intervalo 1 ao 3. Ela representa o seguinte grafo:

[image: Grafo Agregado]

mas ao usar a função 'degree' para o 'grafo' 'graphAgre', me da um erro informando que a váriavel graphAgre é uma lista, não um grafo. Como eu modifoco ela para ser grafo, e assim, calcular o grau?

*É necessário o uso da função degree, pois também irei calcular o closeness e o betweenness.

**(graphAgre)

```
[[1]]

IGRAPH DNW- 4 5 -- 

+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n), Count (e/n)

+ edges (vertex names):

[1] a->c a->d b->d c->d d->b

**typeof(graphAgre)

[1] "list"
`
```

Comment: Infelizmente não estou conseguindo reproduzir o seu problema. Não estou conseguindo nem rodar até onde você cria o `graphAgre`. Você poderia editar a sua pergunta colocando um código reproduzível?

Comment: Isso é um código executável :S Acabei de testar, e funciona.

Comment: Não sem ter os dados graph.txt... Se você postar o resultado de `dput(g)`, vai ficar mais fácil.

Comment: Ta escrito lá em cima "graph.txt":

Comment: Está, mas quando colo o que tá ai em um txt e tento ler, da erro no seu codigo...

Comment: Tenta colocar uma nova linha vazia no final do arquivo :D

Comment: Ja coloquei, mas ele n tem nome de colunas...

Comment: Eiita Daniel!!! Ponha isso aqui no inicio do arquivo. Na primeira linha:
VertexFrom VertexTo TimeStart TimeStop 

Demorei que só para descobrir isso aushasu foi mal.